# Revolution Slider speed

Tags: jquery, slider, flexslider

I am unable to reduce the speed for the main slider on the following website:

http://offshorecompanylicense.com/test4/index.html

It is taking more than 8 seconds to move to the next image. I would like to reduce the speed to 2 seconds.
Please help.

Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your **SLIDER REVOLUTION SCRIPTS** as follows

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.fullwidthbanner').revolution(
        {
          delay:2000,
          startwidth:1080,
          startheight:500,
          hideThumbs:10
        });
});
```